# Storing a string in DB vs list

Tags: python, database-design, relational-database

I have a list of characters of various length, as ['A','B','B','A','A','B']
I need to store it in the DB. Right now I'm converting it to a string which works just fine, but I was wondering what is more pythonic.
In this specific case the sequence matters, but I would like to know the general, preferred options (if the list members were strings themselves, for instance)

Thanks

Edit:
The code I have is something along

> list = ['A','B','B','A']
>
> shuffle(list)
>
> str = ''.join(list)

the string itself gets stored in the database. I'm not looking for a solution to my specific code/problem and I have no performance issues- I want to know if there's any rules of thumb regarding storing blobs in database as far as python is concerned, since some stuff like dictionaries and objects seem reasonable to serialize and store. perharps this is more of a DB question than a python question.

Comment: please tell us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: and also please provide example input and output as it is not very clear from the question

Comment: A list of characters in a sequence is the definition of a string; so converting from a `list` to a string seems logical, and if nothing else, pythonic is logical. So what do you feel is very unpythonic about it? If its your actual code, edit your question with the code you are using and perhaps something can be improved there.

Comment: I don't feel it unpythonic - for my purposes it's great. But if my characters where strings or more complex structures (i.e list in list) that would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Most good database bindings will allow you to store value-semantic Python objects directly (e.g. PyMongo).  If your database only accepts strings, you need to choose a serialisation format; in Python this typically means choosing between pickle (fast but non-human-readable) and YaML (slower, human-readable, language-independent).

pickle:

```
>>> from cPickle import dumps, loads
>>> dumps(['A', 'BB', 'CCC'])
"(lp1\nS'A'\naS'BB'\np2\naS'CCC'\np3\na."
>>> loads(dumps(['A', 'BB', 'CCC']))
['A', 'BB', 'CCC']
```

YaML:

```
>>> from yaml import dump, load
>>> dump(['A', 'BB', 'CCC']) 
'[A, BB, CCC]\n'
```

If you're using a SQL database and want to be able to query within the list, then normalising the database and storing one list item per row is the classic way to solve this problem.

Comment: I think pickle may be overkill for this, since a string can easily be split back into in a list - well you don't need to do it really since strings are sequences (albeit immutable ones) so if all the original poster wanted was to be able to access the characters in the string sequentially then a list would be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what DB you are using, it is hard to give an accurate answer. If your DB only accepts strings you could use `repr()` and `ast.literal_eval` from the standard lib and the combination is pretty fast:

```
In [26]: from yaml import dump, load

In [27]: import ast

In [28]: l= ['A', 'BB', 'CCC']

In [29]: load(dump(l))
Out[29]: ['A', 'BB', 'CCC']

In [30]: ast.literal_eval(repr(l))
Out[30]: ['A', 'BB', 'CCC']

In [31]: %timeit load(dump(l))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit ast.literal_eval(repr(l))
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.6 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong about joining your list and storing string value in database.

In case you want to store items of a different length, eg. ['A', 'AA', 'B', 'AB'] you can always choose some delimiter, '+' for instance. This of course assumes you know that given delimiter cannot be part of any item from your list.

I would sat that for many scenarios above solutions are good enough and there is no 'this-is-not-pythonic' issue with them.

However, this is more DB than python case. There is a [database normalization theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) which gives some advices how to organize your data. You can restructure your data model to the 'first normal form' (1NF), which in your case means that you can create a separate table for storing items (and probably order information) and link it via FK with your current table.

Having this you can save yourself a bunch of problems, eg. items reordering, items counting, etc. But on the other hand this could make your queries more expensive as this solution requires database JOINs to fetch your data from database. In many cases, when designing data model for applications database [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is performed intentionally, mostly because of optimization issues.

To sum up, you should try to predict how you would like to use your data, and having this knowledge choose one of proposed (or maybe a different!) solution.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest I'm not entirely sure what your question is. What DB are you referring to? What do you understand as a general case as opposed to the processing the sequence as is?
However, maybe you are interested in something like this: To convert your list to a Sting, do

```
>>> ''.join(['A','B','B','A','A','B'])
'ABBAAB'
```

Since your list elements are Strings themselves, this is the same thing as

```
>>> ''.join(['ABB','AAB'])
'ABBAAB'
```